# Why use two step approach to deleting multiple items with REST

Tags: rest, theory

We all know the 'standard' way of deleting a single item via REST is to send a single DELETE request to a URI `example.com/Items/666`. Grand, let's move on to deleting many at once. As we do not require atomic deleting (or true transaction, ie all or nothing) we could just tell the client 'tough luck, make many requests' but that's not very nice is it. So we need a way to allow a client to request many 'Items' be deleted at once.

From my understanding, the 'typical' solution to this problem is a 'two step' approach. First the client POSTs a list of item IDs and is returned a URI such as `example.com/Items/Collection/1`. Once that collection is created, they call DELETE on it.

Now, I see that this works just fine, except to me, it is a bad solution. Firstly, you are forcing the client to make two requests to accommodate the server. Secondly, 'I thought DELETE was supposed to delete an Item?', shouldn't calling DELETE on this URI effectively cancel the transaction (it's not a true transaction though), how would we even cancel it? Really would be better if there was some form 'EXECUTE' action, but I can't rock the boat *that* much. It also forces the server to have to consider 'the JSON that was POSTed looks more like a request to modify these Items, but the request was DELETE... so I guess I will delete them'. This approach also starts to impose a sort of state on the client/server, not a true state I will admit, but it is sort of.

In my opinion, a better solution would be to simply call DELETE on `example.com/Items` (or maybe `example.com/Items/Collection` to imply this is a multiple delete) and pass JSON data containing a list of IDs that you wish to delete. As far as I can see, this basically solves all the problems the first method had. It is easier to use as a client, reduces the work the server has to do, is truly stateless, is more semantic.

I would really appreciate the feed back on this, am I missing something about REST that makes my solution to this problem unrealistic? I would also appreciate links to articles, especially if they compare these two methods; I am aware this is not normally approved of for SO. I need to be able to disprove that only the first method is truly RESTfull, prove that the second approach is a viable solution. Of course, if I am barking up the wrong tree do tell me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have spent the last week or so reading a fair bit on REST, and to the best of my understanding, it would be wrong to describe either of these solutions as 'RESTfull', rather you should say that 'neither solution goes against what REST means'.

The short answer is simply that REST, as laid out in [Roy Fielding's dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm) (See chapter 5), does not cover the topic of how to go about deleting resources, singular or multiple, in a REST manor. That's right, there is no 'correct RESTful way to delete a resource'... well, not quite.

REST itself does not define how delete a resource, but it does define that what ever protocol you are using (remember that REST is not a protocol) will dictate the how perform these actions. The protocol will *usually* be HTTP; 'usually' being the key word as Fielding [will point out,](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) REST is not synonymous with HTTP.

So we look to HTTP to say which method is 'right'. Sadly, as far as HTTP is concerned, both approaches are viable. Yes 'viable'. HTTP will allow a client to send a POST request with a payload (to create a collection resource), and then call a DELETE method on this new collection to delete the resources; it will also allow you to send the data within the payload of a single DELETE method to delete the list of resources. HTTP is simply the medium by which you send requests to the server, it would be up to the server to respond appropriately. To me, the HTTP protocol seems to be rather open to interpretation in places, but it does seem to lay down fairly clear guide lines for what actions mean, how they should be dealt with and what response should be given; it's just it is a 'you should do this' rather than 'you must do this', but perhaps I am being a little pedantic on the wording.

Some people would argue that the 'two stage' approach cannot possibly be 'REST' as the server has to store a 'state' for the client to perform the second action. This is simply a misunderstanding of some part. It must be understood that neither the client nor the server is storing any 'state' information about the other between the list being POSTed and then subsequently being DELETEd. Yes, the list must have been created before it can deleted, but the server does not remember that it was client alpha that made this list (such an approach would allow the client to simply call 'DELETE' as the next request and the server remembers to use that list, this would not be stateless at all) as such, the client must tell the server to DELETE that specific list, the list it was given a specific URI for. If the client attempted to DELETE a collection list that did not already exist it would simply be told 'the resource can not be found' (the classic 404 error most likely). If you wish to claim that this two step approach does maintain a state, you must also claim that to simply GET an URI requires a state, as the URI must first exist. To claim that there is this 'state' persisting is misunderstanding what 'state' means. And as further 'proof' that such a two stage approach is indeed stateless, you could quite happily have client alpha POST the list and later client beta (without having had any communication with the other client) call DELETE on the list resources.

I think it can stand rather self evident that the second option, of just sending the list in the payload of the DELETE request, is stateless. All the information required to complete the request is stored completely within the one request.

It could be argued though that the DELETE action should only be called on a 'tangible' resource, but in doing so you are blatantly ignoring the REpresentational part of REST; It's in the name! It is the representational aspect that 'permits' URIs such as `http://example.com/myService/timeNow`, a URI that when 'got' will return, dynamically, the current time, with out having to load some file or read from some database. It is a key concept that the URIs are not mapping directly to some 'tangible' piece of data.

There is however one aspect of that stateless nature that must be questioned. As Fielding describes the 'client-stateless-server' in section 5.1.3, he states:

```
We next add a constraint to the client-server interaction: communication must
  be stateless in nature, as in the client-stateless-server (CSS) style of
  Section 3.4.3 (Figure 5-3), such that each request from client to server must
  contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, and
  cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server. Session state is
  therefore kept entirely on the client.
```

The key part here in my eyes is "cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server". Now I will grant you that 'context' is somewhat open for interpretation. But I find it hard to see how you could consider storing a list (either in memory or on disk) that will be used to give actual useful meaning would not violate this 'rule'. With out this 'list context' the DELETE operation makes no sense. As such, I can only conclude that making use of a two step approach to perform an action such as deleting multiple resources cannot and should not be considered 'RESTfull'.

I also begrudge somewhat the effort that has had to be put into finding arguments either way for this. The Internet at large seems to have become swept up with this idea the the two step approach is the 'RESTfull' way doing such actions, with the reasoning 'it is the RESTfull way to do it'. If you step back for a moment from what everybody else is doing, you will see that either approach requires sending the same list, so it can be ignored from the argument. Both approaches are 'representational' and 'stateless'. The only real difference is that for some reason one approach has decided to require two requests. These two requests then come with follow up questions, such as how 'long do you keep that data for' and 'how does a client tell a server that it no longer wants that this collection, but wishes to keep the actual resources it refers to'.

So I am, to a point, answering my question with the same question, 'Why would you even consider a two step approach?'

Comment: I don't think the point of REST is that the server can't have **any** state (e.g., state is needed to map the IDs in your list to *something* on the server), but that it doesn't have any *per-session* state. As such, either method probably qualifies, though I agree that the one step approach is still probably preferable.

Comment: How do you come to conclusion that the one step approach contains per-session state? I thought I made it clear that neither approach would require a per-session state, like is so often used for something like a shopping cart.

Comment: I didn't come to any such conclusion -- I just concluded that the "state" involved in the two-step approach does not (necessarily) violate the ideas of REST.

Comment: Oh right, I see what you mean now. Well, I still don't consider the two step approach to make use of a 'state'. But As I said 'store context' is some what lose a term. You could twist that intended meaning say 'GETting data makes use of stored context and is thus not REST'. I think my key point though was that both approaches are 'valid' 'RESTfull' approaches that you have to think about to conclude which to use.

Answer (score 3):

IMO:

HTTP DELETE on existing collection to delete all of its member seems fine. Creating the collection just to delete all of the member sounds odd. As you yourself suggest, just pass IDs of the to be deleted items using JSON (or any other payload format). I think that the server should try to make multiple deletes an internal transaction though.

Comment: As far as you are aware, is their any *technical* reason why you can not send a payload in the body of a DELETE request like this? From what I've read of the HTTP spec; all request methods, unless otherwise stated, can have a message body, and the DELETE request does not say otherwise. Though to re-empt nit pickers, yes it's a 'entity'

Comment: I am not aware of any problem with payload in DELETE. We have been using it in both DELETE and in GET (don't ask) methods.

Comment: (that actually makes sense). See, I am going to be dealing with an interface where you want to be sent bulk actions; hundreds of creates, deletes, updates in one go. This is down to internal mechanisms meaning we can process faster then receiving one at a time. Curious, how would *you* achieve this? do you know of any resources that discus these two approaches? To me it seems rather simple, a signal request is easier to use, and saves the server having to worry about things such as how long it keep these lists for.

Comment: Some HTTP servers do not support a body on a DELETE and some clients, notably Apache, do not support sending a body with a DELETE.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that HTTP *already* provides a method of deleting multiple items in the form of [persistent connections and pipelining](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1). At the HTTP protocol level it is absolutely fine to request idempotent methods like DELETE in a pipelined way - that is, send all the DELETE requests at once on a single connection and wait for all the responses.

This may be problematic for an AJAX client running in a browser since few browsers have pipelining support enabled by default. This is not the fault of HTTP, though, it is the fault of those specific clients.

Comment: That is effectively multiple single delete requests done through a 'persistent' pipe. So it's really just a work around (and not that bad a one) for handling the fact that, fundamentally, HTTP works on one resource per request.