# Why is not a good practice to have an entity body in a HTTP DELETE request?

Tags: java, http, rest, web, protocols

I am working with **Restful Web Services** using **Java** and **JAX-RS** and I came across the issue of sending a `DELETE` request with an entity body.

I spent a couple of hours looking for a way to send a `DELETE` request with a message in the body but the only thing that I found was a [work around using the Apache HttpClient](https://code.google.com/p/rest-client/source/browse/restclient-lib/src/main/java/org/wiztools/restclient/http/EntityEnclosingDelete.java).

Some of the answers I found are saying that it does not make sense to have a body in `DELETE` requests and as I see it many servers are supporting this by not allowing a `DELETE` with body.
e.g. "[entity enclosing DELETE requests make no sense](http://httpcomponents.10934.n7.nabble.com/Entity-body-for-delete-td11617.html#message11618)"

So my question is why it is not a good practice to have a body in a `DELETE` request? What is the drawback on this?

Thanks

Comment: Probably because there is no real reason to include a body in the response. As long as you know the DELETE was processed successfully, why would you care about a response message?

Comment: If you allow things that have no meaning, eventually someone will have a "bright idea" and begin using that possibility for an unintended approach with unintended consequences. To put an analogy, web browsers "forgiving" HTML errors resulted in a WWW with tons of malformed pages that could be displayed in some browsers but not in others.

Comment: @TimCastelijns I am asking about the body in the request not the response. Passing data that would assist the delete process.

Comment: Can you give an example of data that you would want to pass in the body that you can't stick in the URI?

Comment: @Gimby The simplest thing that I can think is deleting records from a database table using the primary key as identifier. I understand that this can be done using the URI but what if you want to delete multiple records? Isn't it better to pass the info in the body than performing multiple requests?

Comment: @NikosDim ah right I misread. In that case see the posted answer

Answer (score 4):

The DELETE method requests that the origin server delete the resource identified by the Request-URI. and every resource on web server is identified by only URI. thats why it does not make sense to have body in DELETE

Comment: I understand that concept but this limits you on deleting one resource at a time. So what would be a good practice to delete multiple resources? One way is to perform multiple DELETE requests which is obviously not the best option in terms of performance. What else?

Comment: @NikosDim, deep discussion @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085216/why-use-two-step-approach-to-deleting-multiple-items-with-rest will help you in some manner

Answer (score 1):

REST is noisy, and it is likely that a separate DELETE call for each resource was the intent. For a limited number of ids, you could use a query param on the collection resource:

```
DELETE /widgets?id=1,2,4,16,256
```

In general, you should be able to use query params as filters on a DELETE of a collection just like you would on a GET of that collection.

Comment: As you say it is for a limited number. If someone has long ids then you can easily hit a URL limit, something that could be avoided if you put all this information in the body of a DELETE request.

Comment: Well, you can do what you want, but many frameworks and containers will misbehave if you try to pass a body for a DELETE request. How they misbehave varies by application. Test thoroughly.